# Add existing digital signature to the pdf file Signature Dictionary

Tags: c#, itext, aspose

i sign a pdf file and get signed data (byte[]), how can i add this signed data to the pdf Signature Dictionary section.

Comment: You say you *sign a pdf file and get signed data* - but in what state do you sign it? As you are talking about a *pdf Signature Dictionary* you appear to be aware that the PDF must be prepared first (adding a new signature field or using an existing empty one; adding a signature dictionary as value of the field, ...), so you did prepare the PDF that way before you calculated the hash of that prepared PDF minus the signature placeholder, didn't you?

Comment: No actually. I was thinking of taking the hash digest of the pdf file, signing it, and then putting it inside the pdf file. What actions need to be taken? After the pdf file is prepared, how can I sign it on the signature API and add the result to the pdf file?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096) first.

Comment: Looks like you already have posted [this](https://forum.aspose.com/t/add-existing-digital-signature-to-the-pdf-signature-dictionary/277308) question in Aspose.PDF support forum. You can please follow up there and provide requested details so that it can further be investigated. This is Asad Ali and I am Developer Evangelist at Aspose.